# Django test database username

Tags: python, django, postgresql, gitlab-ci-runner

I am starting a Django project and I am using gitlab's ci/cd on the shared runners and I use Postgres as the database. 
I have this weird problem that it seems like Django is creating the test database with the username "postgres" and I can't find a way to configure it's setting and change it to use the role named "runner". This causes a break in my ci/cd pipeline.

here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: python:3.6.5

services:
  - postgres:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: asdproject
  POSTGRES_USER: runner
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: asdpassword

test:
  script:
  - whoami
  - export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/asdproject
  - export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python manage.py test -   settings=asd.gitlab_runner_settings
```

and my `gitlab_runner_settings.py` file:

I tried many forms of changing settings.py that were recommended in questions but neither worked.

```
from asd.with_debug_settings import *
import sys

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'asdproject',
        'USER': 'runner',
        'PASSWORD': 'asdpassword',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'asdtest',
            'USER': 'runner'
        },
    }
}
```

The error I get while running my pipeline script in gitlab is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: role "postgres" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 26, in run_from_argv
super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 56, in handle
failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 607, in run_tests
self.teardown_databases(old_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 41, in teardown_databases
self._wipe_tables(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 33, in _wipe_tables
"""
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: role "postgres" does not exist

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a host

```
'HOST': 'postgres',
```

this is wrong

It should be either 'localhost' or the address of remote server ip

Comment: I used it from gitlab's own documents. It is correct and it's related  to the way services are linked to runners.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because when gitlab-ci runs tests it creates database according to the settings set in you yml file:

```
variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: asdproject
  POSTGRES_USER: runner
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: asdpassword
```

So `runner` role and `asdproject` database is created. 
But you set your database url as `DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/asdproject`
Where `postgres` user is set.

Please try `DATABASE_URL=postgres://runner:asdpassword@postgres:5432/asdproject`

Comment: It didn't fix anything. I even commented the line defining `DATABASE_URL` and took the same output.

Comment: Does your app use in DATABASE settings`postgres` user? Not in tests, but common settings?

Comment: If you mean in Django's main settings.py file, no I don't.